# JavaScript context.arc() not drawing a Circle, but an Oval instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Hello I have a simple question. I am trying to draw a circle with ctx.arc(), but the output is always an oval. May I know what is my mistake here?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.arc(300, 130, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">My Canvas</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas needs to know the number of logical pixels in both height and width to draw the shapes in the right dimensions.

Explicitly set the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) property of the canvas to fix the drawing.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 640;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.arc(300, 130, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">My Canvas</canvas>
```

Alternatively you could also set the properties as attributes in your HTML.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.arc(300, 130, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="640">My Canvas</canvas>
```